# how add relation between two business objects in stimulsoft report

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

I have two class

```cs
public class PrintMoredKhesarat
{
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    public string BimeGozarName { get; set; }
    public string BimeShodeName { get; set; }
    public string PRVNO { get; set; }
    public string HVNO { get; set; }
    public string MablaghElamShodeKhesarat { get; set; }
    public string MablaghKolKosorat { get; set; }
    public string MablaghTakhfif { get; set; }
    public string MablaghKhesaratPardakhtShode { get; set; }
}
```

And

```cs
public class PrintKosorat
{
    public decimal MoredKhesaratID { get; set; }
    public string ItemKosorat { get; set; }
    public string MablaghKosorat { get; set; }
    public string Sharh { get; set; }
}
```

I'm rebuild and add `dll` to business objects.two class is master - detail.

I want add relation between two business objects.but `ParentDataSource` and `ChildDataSource` is empty.

[image: stimulsoft report]

How add relation between two business objects in stimulsoft report?